# C++ program, JSON reader and extract.

Tags: c++, json, extract

I'm working on an assignment, which has to read a json file and store it in string buffer array. Using struct Collection to collect the object, name and value pair.

Sample JSON:

```
0    {
1       "Obj": {
2          "Hello": "working",
3          "Test": "working"
4    }
```

I am able to extract this, and store it in the struct Collection. I am using: (in a loop)

```
if(buffer[line_number].find('{')!=string::npos) {
```

then using substr to store it.

The problem is that this will not allow if "{" contains in the object or the name-value pair.

```
{
   "Obj": {
      "Hello": "Working {Not working}"
}
```

**{** contians in the value.

```
struct Collection {

   string ObjName;
   string name[50];
   string Value[50]
}
```

Comment: What's magical about the number 50?  See [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).  See also the existing C and C++ implementations of [conforming JSON parsers at json.org](http://www.json.org/) for a survey of techniques in implementing one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm know, this pretty old question, but try use github. There are lot of cool parsers

https://github.com/search?l=C%2B%2B&o=desc&q=json&s=stars&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93

And even mine: https://github.com/kurzgame/json-to-map

Comment: could you post some relevant content from your links?